# How to loop json in android?

Tags: java, android

```
{  
   "contacts":[  
      {  
         "state":"active",
         "name":"xxxx",
         "email":"xxxx@gmail.com",
         "address":"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
         "gender":"male"
      },
      {  
         "state":"inactive",
         "name":"Jyyyy",
         "email":"johnny_depp@gmail.com",
         "address":"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
         "gender":"male"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is an example json. I have created different xml layout for my list adapter with respect to the state of the person like if he is active or inactive etc. Each layout consist different information's. When i run my code all the data are shown in the layout of last state in json. For example if i run the above json "state:active" also comes in the inactive layout. How can i show them in different layouts? should i use different adapters for each state?

```
if (state.equals("active")) {

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SecondActivity.this, oslist, R.layout.list_sec,
            new String[]{TAG_NAME, TAG_COUN, TAG_API, TAG_TEAM1, TAG_TEAM2, BAT_NAME, BAT_DESC, BOWL_NAME, BOWL_DESC, TAG_MATCHID},
            new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.coun, R.id.api, R.id.team1, R.id.team2, R.id.batteam, R.id.batdesc, R.id.bowlteam, R.id.bowldesc, R.id.full});

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //  Object obj = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            String selected = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.full)).getText().toString();

            //   Log.v("url", "Creating view..." + name);
            // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Four.class);
            // sending data to new activity
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("id3", selected);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

} else if (state.equals("hold")) {
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SecondActivity.this, oslist, R.layout.list_preview,
            new String[]{TAG_NAME, TAG_COUN, TAG_API, TAG_TEAM1, TAG_TEAM2},
            new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.coun, R.id.api, R.id.team1, R.id.team2});
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

if (state.equals("inactive")) {
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SecondActivity.this, oslist, R.layout.list_stump,
            new String[]{TAG_NAME, TAG_COUN, TAG_API, TAG_TEAM1, TAG_TEAM2, BAT_NAME, BAT_DESC, BOWL_NAME, BOWL_DESC, TAG_FLAGA, TAG_FLAGB},
            new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.coun, R.id.api, R.id.team1, R.id.team2, R.id.batteam, R.id.batdesc, R.id.bowlteam, R.id.bowldesc, R.id.flaga, R.id.flagb});
}
```

Comment: I can not see   ArrayList

Comment: sorry.. that was supposed to be a json.

Comment: You need to implement a custom `Adapter`.

Comment: @XaverKapeller: can u please be little more elaborate?

Comment: Don't worry, I was already planning on writing an answer.

Comment: Can you post the layout files you have?

Comment: Its quite big. can i send to your mail id?. If ok sgive me your id.

Comment: @XaverKapeller: Layout files: 1.http://pastebin.com/46NHEDNk              2.http://pastebin.com/u1cWiwjw                                          activity:

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to loop the `JSONArray`, if so:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("contacts");
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
    JSONObject contact = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String state = contact.getString("state"); //Here you can get "state" for each contact
}
```

Comment: I have no problem in looping.. Problem is i could not check condition for each "state". It always take the final "state" in the json.